# Aligning arrow with content view with custom iPad popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I am customizing the appearance of my popovers by subclassing UIPopoverBackgroundView. Everything is working fine, except there are some instances where there is a gap between the arrow and the content view. If I keep rotating the device to dismiss the popover then bring it back up, sometimes they line up and others they do not. I'm logging the frame sizes and they are consistently the same, so I have no idea what's going on. I'm attaching screenshots and my layoutSubviews code below.

Where you see me subtracting 4 in the case of arrow direction right this was based on trial & error of getting it to work at least some of the time. I hate coding like this because I'm not sure what this space of 4 points is and why I don't need it in all cases of arrow direction, for example.

In the images the 1st shot shows the problem. This happened on a random triggering of the popover. The next image shows it randomly working when triggered later within the same execution of the app.

Also worth mentioning, I found some sample code at http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/customizing-the-design-of-uipopovercontroller and tried this version of layoutSubviews, even though it's already very similar to what I have. Even with this code I was still seeing the same issue.

EDIT: Worth mentioning it might be obvious from my screenshots but I am not including a border for my popover:

```
+ (UIEdgeInsets)contentViewInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Possibly also worth mentioning I am not using an image file for my arrow image but rather am drawing it custom. Again, even when I comment out the drawing I'm still having the issue, so I don't think it's related, but wanted to mention it for full disclosure.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
CGSize arrowSize = CGSizeMake(kCMAPopoverBackgroundViewArrowBase, kCMAPopoverBackgroundViewArrowHeight);
// Leaving code out for drawArrowImage - even when I leave the arrowImageView as 
// an empty image view and set a non-clear background color this gap is still 
// sporadically showing up
self.arrowImageView.image = [self drawArrowImage:arrowSize];

float arrowXCoordinate = 0.0f;
float arrowYCoordinate = 0.0f;
CGAffineTransform arrowRotation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

float borderMargin = 2.0f;

switch (self.arrowDirection) {
    case UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp:
        arrowXCoordinate = ((self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f) - (arrowSize.width / 2.0f));
        arrowYCoordinate = 0.0f;
        break;

    case UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown:
        arrowXCoordinate = ((self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f) - (arrowSize.width / 2.0f));
        arrowYCoordinate = self.bounds.size.height - arrowSize.height;
        arrowRotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        break;

    case UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft:
        arrowXCoordinate = 0.0f - (arrowSize.height / 2.0f) + borderMargin;
        arrowYCoordinate = ((self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f) - (arrowSize.height / 2.0f));
        arrowRotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight:
        arrowXCoordinate = self.bounds.size.width - arrowSize.height - 4.0f;
        arrowYCoordinate = ((self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f) - (arrowSize.height / 2.0f));
        arrowRotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        break;

    default:
        break;

}

self.arrowImageView.frame = CGRectMake(arrowXCoordinate, arrowYCoordinate, arrowSize.width, arrowSize.height);
[self.arrowImageView setTransform:arrowRotation];
```

[image: Here is an example of the issue happening on a random occurrence]

[image: This is an example of it not happening on another random occurrence on the]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your arrow image square? If not, I'm guessing that the transform is affecting its frame slightly and this is generating the unexpected gap.

Comment: It's not. Let me log the frame of the image view and see if this is happening. Not sure why it's not happening consistently if this is the case but good thought. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I think I remember running into something similar, hope this helps track it down.

Comment: Making the image view frame square solves it, but then the arrow is skewed. Since I do not want it to be square, could I just add autolayout constraints on the width & height for this view? How do I do so? I'm Googling it now but so far haven't found it, just more complicated examples of setting constraints with visual format. Thanks! Though now that I think of it since it's not skewing I don't need to constrain the width & height - what should I do if I don't want my arrow to be square?

Comment: Figured out how to add height & width constraints and as expected, since the image wasn't skewing, still see the problem.

Comment: My thinking was that if your image is rectangular (looks like it's wider than it is high) then add transparent padding to the image file above the tip of the arrow. Is this where you added the padding? And still seeing the problem?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Ok, let me give that a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are getting subpixel values in your calculations (most likely 0.5)

Try using `floorf` or `ceilf` to make sure your values are landing exactly on pixel integral values.

For example...

```
arrowXCoordinate = floorf(((self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f) - (arrowSize.width / 2.0f)));
```

See [floor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor) reference.

Comment: Tried this but still same issue. Thanks.